# Common Regular Expression for java and Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, syntax, rules

I am looking to have a common framework to write some syntactic validation rules in regular expressions so that I can use them in both frontend and backend.
I am using javascript for the front end and java for the backend.
I want to do a form submission on the front end, but before submitting the form, I need to perform some syntactic rule checking. When request come to the backend, I want the same set of rules to be evaluated.

I want to put these rules at one common place where javascript and java code can load from so that I only need to change the rules at this common place and they will be reflected to both the frameworks.

Comment: You can use the JavaScript regular expression in your Java code via [`javax.script`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.scripting/javax/script/package-summary.html).